# Slash Navigation and Jquery

Tags: ajax, url, jquery, hashchange

So I've been wondering how sites like google plus and github navigate. for example when you go to plus.google.com and then click profile it will take you to  something like plus.google.com/112578301581290773086/posts, but it won't reload the entire page.

I have been using hashchange and $.load but its not exactly what I want and doesn't allow for a directory type set up.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page) should provide the information you seek

Comment: thanks that helps a lot. But how does it know to go to plus.google.com instead of looking for a file at plus.google.com/23434/posts? like if you type in the url or something